# Can I get the post id when trying to make a new post using xmlrpc?

Tags: api

When you are trying to make a post manually, for example: example.com/wp-admin/post-new.php the ?p={postid} is already set.

What I'm trying to do is get the {postid} while trying to make a new post using xmlrpc, is this possible?

this is the code I'm using. I can get the postID after I made a new post, but I can't get the {postid}. I wanna put it on $pcontent.

**Update: I really can't get the postID it echo automatically when your code executed sucessfully**

```
<?php
$blogid = 0;
$username = 'admin';
$password = '123';
$method = 'wp.newPost';
$title = "TEST";
$pcontent = "I'm the post content.";
$categories = array('Cat 1', 'Cat 2');
$post_status = 'publish';  
$custom_fields = array('cccId' => '12345', 'cccType' => 'news');
$content = array(
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'post_status' => $post_status,
                'post_title' => $title,
                'post_content' => $blogid,
                'terms_names' => array('category'=>$categories),
                'custom_fields' => $custom_fields
            );

$parameters = array($blogid, $username, $password, $content);
$response = sendRequest($method, $parameters);

function sendRequest($methodName, $parameters)  {
$request = xmlrpc_encode_request($methodName, $parameters);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "localhost/wp/xmlrpc.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1);
$results = curl_exec($ch);
$results = print_r(xmlrpc_decode($results));
curl_close($ch);

return $results;
}
// After the code executed successfully I can get the postID by echo $blog_id which return the postID correctly ;
// If I try to put it inside the code it returns 0;  

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible. The post id is only created during post creation in the database; if you see the post id in the admin editing screen before you hit 'publish' or 'save as draft' then an autosave created the record for you.

If you 'fake' getting the next post id (such as fetching the highest id number from the database and then adding one), there's a risk of a conflict or a race condition - if any other record is created in between your fetch of the next ID and your creation of a database row, then your id will be invalid and incorrect, or will fail to save.

You need to save your post, then edit the post after saving to add the post id in the place you need it.

Comment: I guess I should do that, Create then update it. Thanks